# Can I sort results by encrypted column in TypeORM/PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm coding with NestJS using TypeORM and PostgreSQL database. I created an entity with a `transformer` in order to store encrypted data. Am I able to somehow sort the results by the encrypted column on database side?

Let's say I have an encrypted `name` column. `repository.find({ order: { name: 'ASC' } })` doesn't sort the results by name. I suppose that the results are sorted by **encrypted** name.

Answer (score 2):

That is fundamentally impossible. To sort, you need to know the clear text, which the database doesn't.

Security has a negative impact on usability and performance, that is unavoidable.